# How did Michael move Scylla so easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

Well this question is going to make you think hard. So lay back and think.

In season 4 of Prison Break General Krantz said that it was hard to move Scylla and for the same reason David Baker was kidnapped because moving Scylla was taking time  and he was impatient and scared due to the hijacking attempt made on his card.

But later Michael walks to the hardware, plugs in the six cards and removes the Scylla and takes it with him in his backpack like it was a piece of cake.

So my question is **What was so hard about moving Scylla that General was talking about?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that he was talking about is was difficult to *literally* move. It was more an issue of moving Scylla *securely*.

Think about how hard it was to retrieve Scylla from where it was hidden. It needed 6 cards to unlock, all of which were very heavily protected. They then needed to get all 6 of these cards to a very difficult to reach location. There was a lot of security devoted to it.

In order to move Scylla anywhere safely, the General needed to ensure the following conditions were met:

1. Scylla would have enough protection in transit to its new location, as it would be incredibly vulnerable to being stolen whilst being moved. This is because it would need to be unlocked with the 6 cards first in order to remove it from its secure location.
2. The 6 incredibly important high ranking people with the cards could be safely in the same location at the same time. This meant they would also be vulnerable to an attack, as a congregation of so many important people would be a very big target to any potential enemies.
3. Actually getting the 6 important and busy people to manage their schedules so that they could unlock Scylla, without it being obvious to any corporate spies that the movement was going on that day.
4. The location that Scylla was being transported to could be kept secret, and equally or more secure than its previous location.

This isn't something that is easily organized. The logistics of ensuring all of these things happen simultaneously, and putting the plan together quickly and without anyone knowing would be a mammoth task, even for such a powerful corporation.

Comment: ▲ for creative and realistic reasons.